# Images without being compressed to bitmap?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, png

I have a program that uses pngs and when I put them in the resources they are downgraded to a bitmap that only supports 24 bit color. Is there a way I can keep the image quality from being screwed up?

```
   private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image NSMBWImg = (Image)Properties.Resources.NSMBWImg;
        Image OkamiImg = (Image)Properties.Resources.OkamiImg;
        Game NSMBW = new Game("New Super Mario Bros. Wii", "Nintendo", "Nintendo", "November 15,2009", "Wii", "2D Platformer", "4", "Mario leaps into an all new adventure! Scramble through courses with up to four players at the same time! Run, stomp, and fly through eight worlds packed with enemies and surprises.", NSMBWImg);
        Game Ookami = new Game("Ōkami", "Clover Studio", "Capcom", "PS2: September 19, 2006 Wii: April 15, 2008", "PS2/Wii", "Action-adventure", "1", "Play as the wolf incarnation of the Japanese sun goddess Amaterasu and channel your divine powers through the mighty celestial paintbrush to restore beauty and order to a bleak world overrun by evil.", OkamiImg);
        Games.Add(NSMBW);
        Games.Add(Ookami);
    }
```

I want to make sure the image quality doesn't change, do I possibly just host the image on a website? Or possibly include it in a folder without putting it into resources?

Answer (score 0):

Add the png file to your project ( Right click on your project from Solution Explorer -> Add Existing Item ), then once added in the file properties, set the Build Action to : Embedded Resource.

[image]

To then load your Image

```
    using(Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("<root namespace for the assembly>.<folder name>.<image file name>"))
{
    Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

Another example

```
using (
            Stream stream =
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                        .GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication1.testimage.png")) 
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
        }
```

Comment: I'm not able to change the build action through the properties window, am I doing something wrong? It seems I can only change Build Action on resources and not Solution Items.

Comment: I have added a screenshot - make sure to select the png file in the solution explorer. you should get that option ..

Comment: Alright, I'm getting the error The name 'Assembly' does not exist in the current context and Stream can't be found.

Comment: ok all you need to add is the using System.Reflection; and using System.IO; at the top of your form cs file

Comment: And how do I include them into the List?

Comment: you just type using System.Reflection; using System.IO; your code should already have a bunch of usings .. just add these by typing them. Or if you place your mouse cursor on top of the word Assembly or Stream Visual Studio will prompt you to import the correct namespaces